# Props are not updating correctly when called from inside async post method

Tags: react-redux

Hi I am new to react and working also with react-redux. In my application I want to render different sections according to a prop viewMode.  After clicking post button I expect to render the section of the switch statement that is case: 'result' but I get the above error. I think the problem is that i am updating a value inside an ajax call which is async, because when i do something similar from inside an ordinary method i know it works.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {     
        viewMode: state.viewMode,
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    uvm: actionUpdateViewMode
};
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.postToApi = this.postToApi.bind(this);
    }
    chooseView() {
        switch (this.props.viewMode) {
            case 'result':
                return (
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                Result page
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                );
            case 'start':
                return (
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <h1>Get Result</h1>
                                <button onClick={this.postToApi}>Post</button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                );

            default:
                return null
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            this.chooseView()
        );
    }
    postToApi() {
        let request = {};
        request.fileName ="File1";
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/test';
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileName', request.fileName);
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.uvm({ viewMode: 'result' });
            })

            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error:', error);
            });
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

I am using this

```js
     const mapDispatchToProps = {
            uvm: actionUpdateViewMode
        };
```

to map to an action in redux.
I call this function

```js
    this.props.uvm({ viewMode: 'result' });
```

inside the postToApi() function expecting to render the result of the post but instead i get this error on the browser:

```
Error: Test(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

postToApi function is called from a button click

```html
    <button onClick={this.postToApi}>Post</button>
```

My action file

```
export const UPDATE_VIEW_MODE = 'UPDATE_VIEW_MODE';

export function actionUpdateViewMode(viewMode) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_VIEW_MODE, viewMode: viewMode,
  };
}
```

And the reducer

```
import { UPDATE_VIEW_MODE } from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
  viewMode: 'start'
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_VIEW_MODE:
      return {
        ...state, viewMode: action.viewMode,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

When I am debugging I can see the value of this.prop.viewMode = 'result' but I see it jumps over the conditional statement and doesn't go into it.

I can see others using componentDidMount to make ajax calls, but i don't know how to do that on a button click such as I am doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error in the title is no longer happening, thanks to Ijbc for that. But the real problem is that why i can't go to the block in switch that is 'result'. Most likely because i am updating state from inside a promise. but what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you're calling `chooseView()`, in the switch statement when `viewMode` doesn't match the cases you've provided, it falls through to nothing which resolves to undefined. All you need to do is provide the following in the switch statement...

```js
chooseView() {
        switch (this.props.viewMode) {
            case 'result':
                return (
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                Result page
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                );
            case 'start':
                return (
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <h1>Get Result</h1>
                                <button onClick={this.postToApi}>Post</button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                );
            // Add the below:
            default:
                return null
        }
    }
```

To get it working with setting the state, you need to update the `mapDispatchToProps` so that you're dispatching the action.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   uvm: (mode) => dispatch(actionUpdateViewMode(mode.viewMode))
});
```

Comment: Thank you that removes the error but i like to end up in the  case 'result':. and that still doesn't get me there.

Comment: Just appended the additional issue that's occurring

Comment: Ok so i added the default to the code above and tested it, so it removes the error but i am not getting to the 'result' section. I just get a blank screen.

Comment: Have you amended the `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: Do i have to amend it? and what to?

Comment: If you have a look at the bottom of the answer, I've provided the solution

Comment: After changing to your code i get this error: mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(Test) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
-----------
  Line 21:10:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: Reverting to what it was previously, in the developer tools/Components i can see that the viewMode has been updated: Ref
:
{uvm: ƒ () {}, viewMode: {…}}

viewMode
:
{viewMode: "result"}
viewMode
:
"result"

Comment: But even though the viewMode is updated to 'result' in the switch it gets ignored and drops down to the default. The problem is i think to do with calling 
                this.props.uvm({ viewMode: 'result' }); inside the .then of an async method.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped the `mapDispatchToProps`... it needs to return the object, so it needs to be `(dispatch) => ({ uvm: (mode) => dispatch(action(mode.viewMode)) })`

Comment: It works! Thank you. I updated it to: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
    ({
        uvm: (mode) => dispatch(actionUpdateViewMode(mode.viewMode))
    });